# Regex: Modify regex to accept months in string form (Jan-Feb...)

Tags: regex

I use this regex to validate dates in the form 1/12/2018, uu/12/2018, uu/uu/2018, uu/uu/uu (uu is unknown)

```
(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2})$|(uu\/([1-9]|0[1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])\/[0-9]{4})|(uu\/uu\/[0-9]{4})|(uu\/uu\/uuuu)
```

Is there a way to modify it to accept string months instead of digits? 1-Dec-2018, 1-Jun-2018 etc.

Comment: Use alternation `(?:Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)`

Comment: Can you modify the regex? Because I cant find out where to put it. I didnt wrote this regex, and I cant figure it out.

Comment: Replace where you have used capturing group for months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, just in case someone is looking for it:

```
^(((31(?!\-Feb?|Apr?|June?|Sept?|Nov?))|((30|29)(?!\-Feb?))|(29(?=\-Feb?\-(((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))))|(0?[1-9])|1\d|2[0-8])\-(Jan?|Feb?|Mar?|May?|Apr?|Jul?|Jun?|Aug?|Oct?|Sep?|Nov?|Dec?)\-((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))$|(uu\-(Jan?|Feb?|Mar?|May?|Apr?|Jul?|Jun?|Aug?|Oct?|Sep?|Nov?|Dec?)\-[0-9]{4})|(uu\-uuu\-[0-9]{4})|(uu\-uuu\-uuuu)
```